# Everytime I use a $_ I have to use an @

Tags: php, session, post

ex.

```
$fn = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['fname']));
$ln = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['lname']));
$em = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['email']));
$em2 = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['email2']));
$pd = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['password']));
$pd2 = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, @$_POST['password2']));
```

Same thing happens with $_SESSION

I get an undefined index error if I take the "@" off... 
Any idea why? I don't... all the codes work if I keep them on.

Comment: Are the values actually set? If not simply add an `isset()` test before you try to use the values.

Comment: Yes.  Don't use error suppression, fix the actual error.  In this case you obviously are not checking whether the value is even set before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you check for the existence of a value in the array element using `isset()` before attempting to access it. The reason you're getting an undefined index is because one of those values from your POST data does not exist.

```
if (isset($_POST['fname']))
{
    $fn = htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['fname']));
}
else
{
    $fn = '';
}
```

I'm assuming you know that the @ is. If not, its the error suppression operator. Which turns off error reporting for every instance its used and afterward, it turns error reporting back on. You'll only want to use this when you absolutely have to, as it prevents you from seeing things you might want to see.

Answer (score 1):

That probably means that you're accessing the array's values without checking they're checked or not... 
Either use `isset` or `if ($_POST['fname'])`.

Whatever you do, don't lower your error reporting mode (you're probably at `E_STRICT | E_ALL`). Supressing errors using the `@` is, in my book, bad practice, BTW. The notice is raised internally, so you're slowing down your code, which then looks messy. You're breeding bad habits (turning to the evil `@` sign, instead of fixing the problem)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
foreach (array('fname', 'lname', 'email') as $key) {
   $$key = isset($_POST[$key]) && is_string($_POST[$key]) ? htmlentities(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST[$key])) : '';
}
```

to have variables $fname, $lname, $email and so on. Don't just copy and paste.